# How to make ruby indicate error before a binary function?

Tags: ruby

I have this code that works:

```
stripped = "00010001"
IO.binwrite("Test.txt", [stripped].pack('B*'))
```

But if `stripped` equals to:

```
stripped = "00013001"
```

Ruby writes the "binary" anyway. How can I make Ruby give me a mistake and not write it down?

Comment: Notice that `['00011001'].pack('B*') #=> "\x19"; ['00013001'].pack('B*') #=> "\x19"; ['00015001'].pack('B*') #=> "\x19"`, and `['00012001'].pack('B*') #=> ["00010001"] #=> "\x11"; ['00014001'].pack('B*') #=> "\x11"; ['00018001'].pack('B*') #=> "\x11"`. It's as though only the last bit of 3 (`0b11`), 5  (`0xb101`), 2 (`0b10`), 4 (`0b100`) and 8 (`0b100`) is retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"1000101010".scan(/[^01]/).any?
```

This simply performs a regex on the string looking for any characters that are not `0` or `1` and returns true if the string has any other characters.

Comment: `[^01]`. The second `^` is making the regex scan for characters that are none of `0`, `1`, or `^`, which is not what you want.

Comment: Slightly simpler: `"1000101010".match?(/[^01]/)`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) method of Kernel accepts a base as argument and is strict (by default).

```
Integer("00011001",2).to_s(16) 
# => "19"

Integer("00013001",2).to_s(16) 
# => invalid value for Integer(): "00013001" (ArgumentError)
```